# Filename.xls is locked for editing by 'user name'

Tags: vba

I have a .exe program which opens a macro enabled workbook every 3 minutes. The macro runs on open, then when it finishes the macro .Quit Excel.

never had a problem, but the last few weeks the macro gets stuck and says, Filename.xls is locked for editing by me (My User Name).

I have tried ending Excel from Task Manager, but Excel will not quit. If I sign out of my user session, then sign back in. I can start Excel, and run the macro again.

I have the macro error handles setup to .Quit on all errors, but Excel gets stuck because the macro cannot run to throw an error.

Is there a way to handle this? Something like:

```
If Workbook locked then
    Application.Quit
End If
```

but before the workbook opens?

Comment: File "is locked by editing by me". I expected "locked for editing by another user". Please clarify. If you "sign out of Windows" you can run the macro again. That's a system restart. Are you sure you didn't mean sign out from "Excel"? Please modify your question to clarify. I found this site. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313472/the-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-error-message-when. It deals with the equivalent in Word of what probably is your problem. You may find some hints what solutions to pursue, perhaps the aftermath of an irregular shutdown a few weeks ago.

Comment: This could be a 'multiple open instances of Excel' issue i.e. the workbook is open in one instance of Excel and now you're trying to open it in another instance of Excel. You can use `Windows Task Manager` to confirm this. For example, I have a log workbook that opens automatically with Excel and I have a shortcut to Excel on the Taskbar. Now when I accidentally click twice on Excel in the Taskbar I get your message after the second instance of Excel opens.

Comment: VBasic2008 - I waited to see if the error occurred again today, so I could take screenshots, but it did not. I think you are right about multiple instances of Excel. When the error occurs, I do need to close multiple Excel windows with the same error message showing.  Variatus - The times this has occurred I was unable to close Excel from task manager, so I ended up logging off of my user session, then logging back in.

Comment: This happened again yesterday. I was able to close Excel from Task Manager. there was several instances of Excel open.